# How do I update to v13

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

every time I try to upgrade discord.js v12 to v13, npm reinstalls discord.js v12 and is not upgrading to v13. I tried to delete node_modules, I tried to remove discord.js from package.js and packages-lock.json and it doesn't work. I tried `npm update discord.js`, I tried to uninstall and reinstall discord.js and nothing works, someone, please help me.

Comment: I don’t think v13 is out yet, is it?

Comment: You can always view released npm package versions by visiting the appropriate npm package page (in this case, [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js)) and clicking on the *Versions* tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As of the posting of this answer**

To upgrade to the lastest build of v13 use

```
npm i discord.js@dev
```

This will install the *master* branch of the Discord.js repository. As [EJBEAN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15925814/ejbean) stated, v13 currently is not fully public and is still in active development.

---

**UPDATE**
Discord.JS v13 is now live. To update simply run

```
npm uninstall discord.js
```

Then

```
npm install discord.js
```

Or [View This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68689237/12464931)

Answer (score 1):

v13 has now been released!

To upgrade, use `npm upgrade` or update your `dependencies` in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.0.0"
  }
}
```

Take a look at the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html) for breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because discord.js version 13 is not public yet, so you cannot update to the official v13 version.

In case you want to downgrade (or upgrade)

You can add the package version as a parameter `npm i [packagename]@[version]`. Prefix a version number with a caret (^) or a tilde (~) to specify to install the latest `minor` or `patch` version, respectively.

```
npm i discord.js@12.5.3
```

Alternatively you can install the dev release of djsv13

```
npm i discord.js@^13.0.0-dev.5af2ef5fbc7ad11281f38384c360ae79efe63b39
```

Comment: When trying to install, i get those errors:

```npm WARN deprecated discord.js@13.0.0-dev.5af2ef5fbc7ad11281f38384c360ae79efe63b39: no longer supported```
```npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for discord.js@13.0.0-dev.5af2ef5fbc7ad11281f38384c360ae79efe63b39: wanted: {"node":">=14.0.0","npm":">=7.0.0"} (current: {"node":"14.17.3","npm":"6.14.13"})```
```npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: discord.js@13.0.0-dev.5af2ef5fbc7ad11281f38384c360ae79efe63b39```

Comment: @JaquelineQuébec your npm is outdated you need to update it